# ARB_sync and proper testing

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I came across the concept of [Sync Objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sync_Object), and decided to test them out. They seem to work as expected, but my current test cases are limited.

What would be a proper test to ensure that these sync objects are performing as intended as a means to synchronize the CPU rendering thread with the GPU?

An example use-case for this would be for video capture programs which "hook" into the OpenGL context of a video game, or some other application using OpenGL.

Comment: Does your example need to be multithreaded? I'm not sure how I would implement it without being in the rendering thread.

Comment: Sorry: I realize that was somewhat vague. There is only one rendering thread; the other threads would be doing things such as using mutexes to copy GPU data to raw buffers allocated as client (CPU) memory to other services. I've simplified the question to allow for more flexibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example use-case seems fishy to me.

FRAPS is an example of a program that "hooks" into an OpenGL application to capture video, and it does it very differently. Rather than force a CPU-GPU synchronization, FRAPS inserts an asynchronous pixelbuffer read immediately before `SwapBuffers (...)` is called. It will then try and read the results back the ***next*** time `SwapBuffers (...)` is called instead of stalling while the result becomes available the first time around. *Latency does not matter for FRAPS.*

However, even without the async PBO read, there would be no reason for FRAPS to use a sync object. `glReadPixels (...)` and commands like it will implicitly wait for all pending commands to finish before reading the results and returning control to the CPU. It would really hurt performance, but GL would automatically do the synchronization.

---

The simplest use-case for sync objects is two or more render contexts running simultaneously.

In OpenGL you can share certain resources (including sync objects) across contexts, but the command stream for each context is completely separate and no synchronization of any sort is enforced. Thus, if you were to upload data to a vertex buffer in one context and use it in another, you would insert a fence sync in the producer (upload context) and wait for it to be signaled in the consumer (draw context). This will ensure that the draw command does not occur until the upload is finished - if the commands were all issued from the same context, GL would actually guarantee this without the use of a sync object.

The example I just gave *does not* require CPU-GPU synchronization (only GPU-GPU), but you can use `glClientWaitSync (...)` to block your calling thread until the upload is finished if you had a situation where CPU-GPU made sense.

---

Here is some pseudo-code to evaluate the effectiveness of a sync object:

#### Thread 1:

```
glBindBuffer    (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferSubData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 4096*4096, foo); // Upload a 16 MiB buffer

GLsync ready =
   glFenceSync  (GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE​, 0);
```

#### Thread 0:

```
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

// Try with and without synchronization
if (sync) {
  // Wait up to 1 second for the upload to finish
  glClientWaitSync (ready, GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT, 1000000000UL);
}

// Ordinarily mapping a buffer would wait for everything else to finish,
//   we need to eliminate that behavior (GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT) for this test.
void* bar = 
  glMapBufferRange (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 4096*4096, GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT​);

// When `sync` is true and the sync object is working, bar should be identical to foo
```

Comment: The SwapBuffers call of frame N+1 doesn't necessarily mean that the frame N is finished rendering. In Nvidia drivers for example, the SwapBuffers call itself is usually not blocking, but the first draw call of the frame N+2 is. But yeah, like you said, OpenGL will do the sync for you when you try to map the PBO so it does work even without sync objects.

Comment: @Jerem: Yeah, I didn't mean to imply that actually. I know that frames can be queued up multiple levels deep. But the `SwapBuffers` call is the only time that FRAPS injects any code into the application, and it will check the "ready" state of the PBO before reading the results (which could be multiple frames old by the time it is ready), that's what I was talking about with the latency issues.